# How to register Events using Firebase Analytics

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web) tutorial, I am attempting to register some events using the `firebase.analytics().logEvent()` functionality.

As has been accustomed to firebase, following the documentation alone will not work and some additional work needs to be done.

Somewhere it was written, that events need to first be registered in the Firebase Analytics Dashboard but the dashboard doesn't have this functionality.

Here is my firebaseEventService.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export const AVAILABLE_EVENTS = {
    search: "search",
    select_content: "select_content",
    login: "login",
    join_group: "join_group",
    sign_up: "sign_up",
    spend_virtual_currency: "spend_virtual_currency",
    present_offer: "present_offer",    //item_id, item_name, item_category
    share: "share",                     //content_type, item_id
    add_to_cart: "add_to_cart",        //quantity, item_category, item_name, item_id, item_location_id, value, price, currency
    view_item: "view_item"             //item_id, item_location_id
}

export const reportEvent = (event, params) =>{
    firebase.analytics().logEvent( event, { params } );
};
```

The following reportEvent() runs wo/ exceptions but no events are registered when called in a view as follows:

```
reportEvent(AVAILABLE_EVENTS.share, {
   content_type: "foo",
   item_id: "bar
})
```

Here is my main.js

```
...
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
...
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
firebase.analytics().logEvent("tutorial_begin");
...
```

Although basic analytics works and the default (page_view, etc) are registering, the manual events are not logged and neither the (tutorial_begin) logEvent test. Not sure what I am missing.

Just to note I am running this locally, perhaps there is an issue with that?

Additional documentation on this [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en&ref_topic=9267641).

**EDIT**

The `tutorial_begin` in the main.js is registered correctly and displayed in Events dashboard but when I do the following call, its not being registered:

```
firebase.analytics().logEvent("search", {search_term:"foobar"});
```

This event and its argument "`search_term`" is stated [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735):

Comment: Events are automatically created when you first log them. There is no need (nor way) to pre-register them in the dashboard. If you found a place in the documentation that says otherwise, please provide the link or report a bug in that page.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that no registration is needed for non-custom events. Do you see something off with the code that the events are not being sent out?

Comment: Nope, nothing jumps out. And I have no issues logging custom events myself. Can you maybe elaborate on what "works" vs" not works" means to you here? What are you looking at when you determine it works, or doesn't work?

Comment: Kindly check the EDIT, thank you!

Comment: The code update again looks fine. Are you navigating away from the page by any chance? That could cause the event to not be delivered in time.